# Wordpress blog posts api - get posts by author

Tags: posts, rest-api

Is there a standard route for getting all blog posts by specific author id? I can't find anything obvious. I tried this but I get a 404 error

```
http://localhost:8888/mysite/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?author=125
```

Comment: Is it a vanilla setup? Permalinks on? Can you access other rest endpoints? Seems to work for public WP sites I tested on.

Comment: That URL looks correct to me too. Even if the `author` argument was incorrect, you should get a response with the all posts, not a 404. What are your permalink settings?

Comment: I can access all the other normal endpoints like posts, pages etc. and I can apply other arguments which work too like eg: `author_exclude` . Permalinks are set to 'Post name'.

Comment: So, I just deactivated all plugins and it works. I then activated one by one to find the culprit and it is WordFence. As soon as I activate that I get the 404 error again. I am not sure why this is but it is the plugin responsible.

Comment: Seems like WordFence disables this route to prevent username fishing. There is an option to disable it and the author route works again

Comment: For posterity, the setting in question is located at Wordfence > All Options > Brute Force Protection: "Prevent discovery of usernames through '/?author=N' scans, the oEmbed API, the WordPress REST API, and WordPress XML Sitemaps " - uncheck that box and you're golden

Comment: You can answer your own question, @user8463989. That makes the answer much more explicit for others. Your question and comment were very helpful to me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

So, I just deactivated all plugins and it works. I then activated one by one to find the culprit and it is WordFence. As soon as I activate that I get the 404 error again. I am not sure why this is but it is the plugin responsible.

Seems like WordFence disables this route to prevent username fishing. There is an option to disable it and the author route works again.